# Hbase why regions again split after merging

Tags: hbase, region

```
hbase(main):067:0> version
1.1.2.2.3.2.0-2950, Wed Sep 30 18:24:54 UTC 2015
```

I have a hbase setup with 12 nodes, one of the tables had 36 regions distributed over 11 nodes, I merged consecutive regions online(using `merge_region`) and made 18 regions. After that a minor compaction started and again regions got split and number of regions increased to 32. Why this might happen, how to track and understand this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

That is quite possible. As each hbase region has a property `hbase.hregion.max.filesize` which denotes the maximum file size for any HFile. Whenever HFile size grows and crosses the limit defined in the configuration, it starts splitting process.

Same must happen in your scenario. When you merge 32 partitions and get 18 partitions, HFile size will be relatively more. And it will start splitting the regions into smaller regions once it reaches the max.fileSize.